# format numeric currency to textual Indian number format Android

Tags: java, android

I have some numbers like **100,000** and I want to output as **1 Lakh** in [Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system). is there any method that supports it?

Detailed Example:

Input  5,50,000

Output  5.5 Lakh

Comment: You don't need inbuilt library or method for everything. If you use simple logic then you can achieve what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could try stripping the commas, casting to an integer, the dividing to get the number of Lakhs:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
String input = "5,50,000";
double lakhs = Double.parseDouble(input.replaceAll(",", "")) / 100000;
String out = df.format(lakhs);
System.out.println(out);
```

### Demo

Comment: Not sure what the minimum *lakhs* is but if there is an input of `1` then I think you need `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Actually, if we started off with a large decimal component, we might even want to retain beyond 5 places.

Comment: That is so true